# accessing array through multiple functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

so I'm creating a little program in C and I'm facing an issue to which I do not find any relevant solution. 
Here is my program : I have an array of data. I have a function that fills this array every second. So I declared this array in my `main`, and passed it to my function :

```
readDataLoop((uint16_t tableau []);
```

So far so good. Once this array is filled, I have a function: `stateManager(state)` that is called. I do not pass my array to this function. In this function, my state manager decides to validate the data so I call a function `validateData()` which determines if the data in the array is correct.

Here is my problem : how can my function validateData access the initial array since I did not pass it as a parameter?

What I could do would be to pass the array as a parameter to the state manager, and then pass the array again to the function `validateData()` but that would break my logic. The only argument I want my state manager to have is the state.

I could also declare my array as a global variable, but I'm also trying to avoid this...

Comment: You need to pass it in as an argument or you won't have access to it. Another thing to note is that array is of unknown size so you probably need a secondary `size_t size` argument.

Comment: Isn't it the array that contains the state?

Answer (score 0):

> What I could do would be to pass the array as a parameter to the state manager, and then pass the array again to the function validateData() but that would break my logic. The only argument I want my state manager to have is the state.

Well, you have four options:

1. Make the array a global variable, so that anybody can access it at any time. This is a terrible idea.
2. Pass the array as a parameter to the state manager. You say that this would break your logic, but that doesn't make sense -- if your state manager isn't currently using the array, then nothing in the code could break just because you've added a parameter.
3. Make the array part of the `state` that gets passed into the state manager. That avoids adding the parameter that you seem not to like, while still giving the state manager access to the array, and without using a global variable.
4. Don't call `validateData()` from `stateManager()`, but instead do it from somewhere where you do have access to the array. (Hat tip to Tim Randall, who suggested this in a comment below.)

Comment: Or make the array a `static` and restrict the functions `readDataLoop()` and `validateData()` to forever being in the same source file. Or refactor the code so that the array is validated at a different time? (If validation depends on the current state, then just pass the array around with the state already!)

Comment: I'd wrap the static variable in with option 1, because a static variable is really just a global with limited access. Refactoring is a good option — I'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a quick example of how you might use parameters to pass your arrays between functions, read data, and validate it.

Notice that read data and validate data don't need to have any concept about the data except for type and size.  I've passed in the size, but C doesn't handle different types well.  You'd need to create different functions to handle this, use a common `#define` type, or do some wonky `void *` and type enumeration type stuff.  (C++ has templates to handle this problem...)

Also notice that there really is no state manager here or anything, just a couple functions.  If you wanted to build a true state manager, then the data would really want to be part of that manager.  This again can trail into C++ land, though C can do this sort of thing decently.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int BOOL;
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

// Pass the data by reference and include the number of entries.
// This way we can modify the data.  In C, you almost always pass
// arrays this way as passing arrays by value isn't well supported.
void readData(int *myData, int numEntries)
{
    for(int i=0; i<numEntries; i++)
    {
        myData[i] = i;
    }
}

// validate the data - *myData here could/should be constant.
BOOL validateData(int *myData, int numEntries)
{
    for(int i=0; i<numEntries; i++)
    {
        if(myData[i] != i) 
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

// Using C style defines for constants.  Newer compilers can do it safer.
#define NUM_ENTRIES 10
int main()
{
    int myData[NUM_ENTRIES];

    readData(myData, NUM_ENTRIES);
    if(!validateData(myData, NUM_ENTRIES))
    {
        printf("Bad Data\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Good Data\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I considered showing a global array version, but am against it because it promotes really bad coding habits and is not needed for this case.